# Use PHP variable as Javascript function parameters

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm using Laravel and I have two php variable in my blade view like this:

```
$dropDown = $formDataValue['name']
$emptyDropDown = $formDataValue['name'];
```

And I create a Javascript function with two parameters in same blade view:

```
function autoFill (dropDown, emptyDropDown) {
    $("#" + dropDown ).change(function() { 

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/bcnss",

            success: function(response){

                var dataLength = response.length;
                $("#" + dropDown).empty();
                $("#" + dropDown).append("<option value=''>Select</option>");
                for( var i = 0; i< dataLength; i++){
                    var id = response[i].id;
                    var name = response[i].name;
                    $("#" + dropDown).append("<option value='"+id+"'>" + name + " </option>");
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Then I call this:

```
<?php echo "<script> autoFill(".$dropDown.", ".$emptyDropDown."); </script>"; ?>
```

Problem is they can pass the parameters to function! I check element in browser and I see when I call this function, it's have parameters. But in the script tag, there nothing!

[image]

How I can fix this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `autofill(city, ward)`  would be passing the two _variables_ `city` and `ward` into the function. The rest of your code however seems to indicate that you probably rather want to pass _text strings_ to your function here.

Comment: Put your `city` and `ward` to quotes, as there is no such variables: `<?php echo "<script> autoFill('{$dropDown}', '{$emptyDropDown}'); </script>"; ?>`

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I understood!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you forgot about quotes, when you are passing strings into function.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        autoFill('{{ $dropDown  }}', '{{ $emptyDropDown }}');
    });
</script>
```

You can do it this way, but you shouldn't, because [Laravel Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade) do it for you itself.

```
<?php echo "<script> autoFill('".$dropDown."', '".$emptyDropDown."'); </script>"; ?>
```

Comment: Right he is forgot quotes.

Comment: nope, this is javascript code. you should just add it in your blade below you defined variables and everything will work

Answer (score 3):

You can assign the php value in js variable in blade file like below:

```
<script>
    var dropDown = '{{$formDataValue['name']}}';
    var emptyDropDown = '{{$formDataValue['name']}}';
</script>
```

and then use js file and move the autoFill() function in js file and call that js file in blade using .
and call *autoFill(dropDown, emptyDropDown);* in js file on document.ready Like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    autoFill(dropDown, emptyDropDown);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using laravel try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
autoFill("{{$dropDown}}","{{$emptyDropDown}}");

function autoFill(dropDown,emptyDropDown) {
    console.log("hi");
}
```

Hope its helpfull

not using core php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
autoFill("<?=$dropDown?>","<?=$emptyDropDown?>");

function autoFill(dropDown,emptyDropDown) {
    console.log(dropDown);
    console.log(emptyDropDown);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not render the values as strings, so javascript interprets them as variables, which are not defined.

so instead of `autofill(city,ward)`

you want `autofill('city','ward')`

1000 ways to rome, this would be one:

```
<?php echo "<script> autoFill('$dropDown', '$emptyDropDown'); </script>"; ?>
```